# How do I remove an EFI System partition from a drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, macos, efi

I have an external HD which used to be my TimeMachine drive. I got a different drive for that, so I want the original drive back as an external on my Windows box, but it has this random 200 MB partition labeled as EFI System Partition. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. On the command prompt type
   ***diskpart*** and answer to any possible [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt.
2. On the new diskpart prompt, type
   ***list disk***. Note the *Disk ###* column.
3. Type, ***select disk ###*** (with

   #### being the disk you wish to delete. Usually the disk with partition 0 with a size of 200 MB)

   NOTE: The disk may not show the 200MB partition in the disk list in Diskpart even if it exists.
4. Finish by typing, **clean**.
5. Type **exit** to exit ***diskpart***

Have fun!

Comment: Very good!  Makes you wonder why this is provided through the UI.

Comment: Since the question was on removing a single partition, it should be noted that the "clean" command removes all partition information from the disk, effectively rendering it a blank disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DBAN](http://www.dban.org/)** to nuke all partitions on the drive (version 2 supports USB) and then create a new partition using Windows Disk Management.

If necessary, backup important data, as everything will be deleted.

Comment: I don't know if I want to use that:

DBAN will automatically and completely delete the contents of any hard disk that it can detect

I have 4 other drives in this machine...

Comment: it CAN, but it will only delete the content of the drive you SELECT, big difference :) you may of course disable the internal drives in the BIOS or even disconnect them physically and only leave the USB drive connected and thus detectable, if it makes you feel safer, but this is not necessary. you will be presented with a choice of drives and then you select the USB HDD and let DBAN do its thing.