# Is it safe to remove EFI System Partition?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, efi

From this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/47364/29353) , I know how to remove a EFI System Partition . But is it safe to remove it ? The EFI partition appears in an empty disk . I have already removed all other partitions.

I used to install Hackintosh before, maybe that's why the EFI System Partition appears ( just a guess ).

Note: The disk is using GPT , and my Operating System is Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't the system boot disk, then sure.

Comment: Although this answer is probably correct in this case, it should also be emphasized that an EFI-based computer must have at least one ESP to boot. Removing the ESP that holds the computer's boot loader(s) will render the computer unbootable. In most cases, the ESP on data disks can be safely removed; it's the one on the boot disk that holds boot loaders. This isn't guaranteed, though; the ESP that holds the boot loader(s) *could* be on a data disk. If in doubt, back up the partition or unplug the disk to see if the computer still boots without the disk before removing the partition.

Comment: I have a Windows 10 and have a **sole disk** and it includes 3 partitions one named `EFI System Partition`, `OS (C:) Boot, Page File Crash Dump, Primary Partition` and finally another saying `Recovery Partition`. Can I then **remove** the _EFI system Partition_ and use it as a Data Partition?